# LuaLaTeX windows system calls not functioning

Tags: luatex, windows

I am using a light version of `LuaLaTeX` provided by `TinyTeX`.

I have a lua file: `githelp.lua`

```lua
function gitlogread()
  local pip=io.popen("echo 'ANYTHING'")
  gitid=pip:read()
  pip:close()
    return tex.print(gitid)
end
```

and my tex file

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\directlua{dofile("githelp.lua")}

\begin{document}
BEGIN
\directlua{gitlogread()}
END
\end{document}
```

I can't under any circumstances get `os.execute` or `io.popen` to return anything from the system, regardless of how trivial it is.

I have tried using `--shell-escape` although the documentation says it should work regardless. I just want my system calls to return something. Am I missing an important package?

Comment: os.execute is disabled unless you use `--shell-escape` commandline option

Comment: by default you get a Lua error but with `--shell-ecape` [your example produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHMgW.png)

Comment: I am not using the windows binary but `echo` should work it in the cmd commandline.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't a package issue. apparently, it was a command line issue, that I wasn't aware of.

doesnt work:

lualatex my.tex --shell-escape

does work:

lualatex --shell-escape my.tex

Here it looks like the io.popen is enabled unless the --safer flag is used.
[Reference manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf#page=65)

However, the better answer is here: 4.2.4 Executing programs.  I would like a way to put this setting into a configuration file or edit the texconfig in lua. But that may be a future endeavor.